# How to start batch jobs using DataMinder scheduler?

Tags: java, batch-processing

We need to run a batch job each night at 03:00. We have a few processes each built with some tasks.
The idea is to let the processes run each night and download some data files and update other systems.

What I don't understand is how to implement a scheduler ([DMScheduler](https://dataminder.pro/javadoc/pro/dataminder/publicapi/core/dmobjects/package-summary.html)) 
that will start a process every night at a specific time.
There exits general information about plugin development but nothing 
specific about schedulers as far as I can see.

Can someone explain how [DataMinder](https://dataminder.pro) schedulers work and how to implement one as above?
Perhaps some implementation examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2 scheduler methods bellow work with "machine" time (as opposed to "human" time):

```
getNextRunTimeInMilliseconds(long nowInMilliseconds)
setLastStartedTimeInMilliseconds(long lastStartedTimeInMilliseconds)
```

Please see discussion about "machine" and "human" time at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/instant.html

Basically "machine" time is a time stamp in time without any relation to dates, time zones.
"Human" time is a specific date and time in a specific time zone.

This means that in this case you need to transform between the "machine" time and "human" time.

Calls to method getNextRunTimeInMilliseconds(nowInMilliseconds) may be called multiple times by DataMinder and is just a check
to see if next run time has changed because, for example, plugin/scheduler parameters may have changed.
When a process has been started and finished running the method

```
setLastStartedTimeInMilliseconds(lastStartedTimeInMilliseconds)
```

is called  with the last time the process was started and run.

Let's take an example:

Here are some date/times and corresponding time stamps:

```
2016-08-06 03:00:00 = 1470445200000
2016-08-07 03:00:00 = 1470531600000
```

Assume the process was last run "6:th of August 2016, 03:00 CET". This corresponds to time stamp (as Java long) 1470445200000.

When

```
setLastStartedTimeInMilliseconds(1470445200000)
```

is called with above value you need to transfer it to "human" time
"6:th of August 2016, 03:00 CET" and then figure out what the next run time should be.
In this case the next runtime in "human" time would be the day after, that is "7:th of August 2016, 03:00 CET" and this corresponds to
timestamp 1470531600000.

The

```
getNextRunTimeInMilliseconds(nowInMilliseconds)
```

should return the new value
of 1470531600000 which tells DataMinder to run the processes on "7:th of August 2016, 03:00 CET". And when the process
has run a call will be made to

```
setLastStartedTimeInMilliseconds(lastStartedTimeInMilliseconds)
```

and the scheduler must again figure
out what the next run time should be based on the received lastStartedTimeInMilliseconds.

Hope it make things more clear.